# 2 decks of cards, independent probability.

Tags: probability

I have two decks of cards, I will pull at random a single card from each deck. What is the probability that, exactly one card is a queen?

My text book is saying 24/169 after being simplified, but after my working out I get 12/169.  Can someone explain were I am going wrong?

Comment: $\frac {12}{169}$ is the probability that the first deck returns a $Q$ and the second does not (or conversely).  You need to double it to cover both cases.

Comment: Two independent experiments with equal probability on success. [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n=2$ and here $p=\frac4{52}$. To be found: $P(X=1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to show me how you got that result in order that I can explain where you went wrong.

Anyway, I am showing you the correct way to approach this problem and get the correct answer.

A deck has $52$ cards and out of them, $4$ are queens.

So you can get exactly $1$ queen by choosing a queen from deck $1$ and a non-queen from deck $2$. Similarly you can get exactly $1$ queen by choosing a queen from deck $2$ and a non-queen from deck $1$.

So the probability of getting exactly $1$ queen is 
$= \large\frac{4}{52} \cdot \large\frac{48}{52} + \large\frac{48}{52} \cdot \large\frac{4}{52} $
$= 2 \cdot \large\frac{12}{13^2}$
$= \large\frac{24}{169}$

Now, as far as my intuition goes, you did not consider the $2$ different decks as different cases.

Comment: Your intuition is correct

Answer (score 3):

You can draw exactly one queen in two ways:

1. The card from the first deck is a queen (this has a probability of $(4/52)$) **and** the card from the second is not a queen probability $(48/52)$. "And" translates to multiplication of probabilities (the events are independent), so the probability of this scenario is $$\frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{48}{52}$$ **OR**
2. The card from the first deck is not a queen (48/52) **and** the card from the second is a queen (4/52). "And" translates to multiplication of probabilities, so the probability of this scenario is $$\frac{48}{52}\frac{4}{52}$$
   "OR" translates to addition of probabilities (because the events are mutually exclusive), so in total you have that 
   $$\frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{48}{52}+\frac{48}{52}\cdot\frac{4}{52}=\frac{24}{169}$$

Comment: So it's the probability of getting the card against the probability of not getting the card in both draws of the deck?

Comment: @Jay.Smyth Say the cards are C1 and C2. You draw exactly one queen in the following events: $(C1=\text{queen and} C2=\text{not queen})$ or $(C1=\text{not queen and } C2=\text{queen})$.

Comment: You might add "OR" translates to addition of probabilities *because the events are mutually exclusive*.